# When ratio hides the sign of the numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $x = 10$ and $y = 50$, this implies $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{1}{5} < 1 \Rightarrow x < y$. Why cannot we use the same steps when $x = -10$ and $y = -50$?

Comment: do you know what happen if you multiply a negative number to inequality?

Comment: @AliAmiri Of course I know, but things can get confusing sometimes, in particular when you see this amongst a lot of other stuff ... and this was more like a discussion, not a proper problem to solve

Answer (score 4):

You are multiplying by $y$. If you multiply an inequality by a negative number, you reverse the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

you will then get -10/-50 = 1/5 < 1, right?. And then multiplying buy -50 you will get
-10 > -50 (the sign change side when you multiply or divide by something negative).